# What are the risks of powering fan AC motor with Triac dimmer?

Tags: motor, triac, dimmer

I'm going to replace current resistor potentiometer with arduino-controlled triac scheme, probably [this module.](http://www.inmojo.com/store/krida-electronics/item/8-channel-ac-light-dimmer-module-arduino/)

I'm going to load it with 6 motors , 300W each.

1. How bad the EMI gonna be (would I be able to plug audio amlplifier
   to the same line)?
2. Would it substantially influence reactive power
       section of my electricity bill? I am located in industrial building in the country that has charges for reactive power.

Comment: Note that the dimmer module you linked is _specifically_ designed for resistive loads, which motors are _not_.

Comment: @uint128_t I would think so too, but the description includes "or fan speed"

Answer (score 4):

> What are the risks of powering fan AC motor with Triac dimmer?

1. The speed control may not work very well. Nearly all AC fan motors are induction motors. Induction motors are inherently designed to operate at a speed determined by frequency with very little controllability by voltage reduction. However, low-powered fan motors of the shaded pole and permanent split capacitor (PSC) type of induction motor can be controlled that way. Your 300 watt motors are a little larger than the usual motor (150 W or less) that is controlled that way and may overheat if they are not designed for that duty. They may also have a more limited range of control.
2. Electronic voltage reduction distorts the waveform of the current drawn from the source.

> I'm going to replace current resistor potentiometer with arduino-controlled triac scheme, probably this module.

It appears that you will need to program phase-back firing control for each fan. Have you considered that?

> How bad the EMI gonna be (would I be able to plug audio amlplifier to the same line)?

You will need to design filtering to deal with the EMI

> Would it substantially influence reactive power section of my electricity bill?

A distorted load current has an effect similar to reactive current and will reduce the total power factor, but not the displacement power factor. It is likely that the effect on the meter will be to increase the reactive section of the bill. The percentage increase may be small depending on other loads. The addition to the reactive power is not arithmetic, but proportional to the square root of the sum of the squares of the distortion current and the conventional reactive current.

Comment: What do you mean by "phase-back firing control for each fan"? The program code for Arduino to delay opening of the triac after zero-crossing is ready for this scheme, and I'm planning to use it. Or do you imply that I need more complex algorithm like [NXP's Single Phase AC Induction Motor Control Reference Design](http://cache.nxp.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/DRM039.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf)

Comment: I mean conduction angle control or variable delay of gating after zero crossing. If you have the program code for that, you have simply to implement that for each fan.

Comment: The international standards for motor parameter identification call for the full-load output mechanical power to be marked on the motor rating plate. I have assumed that "6 motors , 300W each" are motor that will produce 300 watts of mechanical power. If you have motors that require 300 W electrical input and produce 150 W mechanical power, they are more in the range of fan motors that are commonly used with slip-control methods.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you need random turn on SSR for motor, not zero cross. Motors will constantly jerking.

EDIT: actualy I'm wrong, the SSRs aren't zero cross, rather the MCU has an input from zero cross detector on board, but without schematics I can't say more, but probably is going to work.

The opto triac is probably MOC3051 as seen from other boards of same brand, which is an enhanced opto triac to work with inductive loads. If problems can occur, you can still mount snubbers between L and outputs L.

1. The EMI: you can install additional EMI filter on mains side if you will encounter problems.
2. Nowdays a phase angle control is still widely used in industry. The phase angle control itself doesn't generate extra reactive power, rather it generate high order harmonics which can be eliminated with use of choke or filter.

Comment: The module linked by the OP has TRIACs with random-turn on control. It just also includes a zero-cross detector that is exposed to the connected microcontroller (which means you'd have to implement the timing logic yourself).

Comment: Universal motors can be speed controlled with triacs just fine, it's how most of the speed controlled power tools like drills, sanders, saws, grinders etc. are speed controlled.

Comment: @jms But the board lacks of snubbers and probably the opto hasn't the aditional RC circuit on trigger side, used for inductive loads control.

Comment: Correct, OP's light dimmer isn't suitable for driving inductive loads. The triggering topology has nothing to do with it however. You misunderstand what zero crossing-delayed turn-on and random turn-on are: they are two alternate approaches to controlling the average voltage with triacs, with random turn on being the cruder, cheaper approach. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18163/what-does-random-phase-means-in-a-triac-driver

Comment: @jms Where did you get this feeling that I misunderstood the difference between ZC and random, just curious.

Comment: Because you wrote that random triggering is required for driving motors.

Comment: @jmm Can you elaborate why this dimmer isn't suitable if your first comment about speed controlled motors hold.

Comment: @jms That's correct, and I can confirm that only random turn on SSR can drive a motor, zero cross circuit isn't suitable.

Comment: Could you find a source on that? I see no reason why random turn on would be better in *any* case, except for the lower cost.

Comment: @jms It's written in all SSR manuals, random on SSRs are all higher priced you won't find it for same price as ZC. They are better because they don't missfire like ZC, with inductive load there is a phase shift voltage/current, so the current is still dropping when ZC occurs, then after voltage is yet rising the current becomes zero and load is never turned on again in that semiperiod, it will wait the next one.

Comment: I thought that maybe triacs are also known as "SSR"s in some other part of the world and failed to make the mental connection to "solid state relay", since OPs "dimmer" has nothing at all to do with them, being just a PCB with bare triacs, optoisolators for the gates and a zero crossing detector. Now I understand, you were talking about triac-based (ZC) SSRs and transistor-based (random turn on) SSRs, while I was talking about different triac power control methods (random and phase angle AKA ZC triggering).

Comment: And yes, OPs triac card is not suitable for driving inductive loads as-is for the same reason that a triac SSR is not suitable. I'm sorry for the confusion on my part, but to be honest you could have pre-empted this by spelling out acronyms such as "SSR" in order to avoid misunderstandings.